# localizing app name in desktop bridge apps

Tags: desktop-bridge

i have a desktop app to convert to `uwp` apps, it has a different app name on different system language, I knew to do this in `uwp` project, setting the package display name with `ms-resource:AppName`, but in desktop bridge apps it didn't work,
can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions on how to do this are in the ["Using MRT for Desktop Apps" whitepaper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/using-mrt-for-converted-desktop-apps-and-games). Basically you need to build a PRI file with your resources and then reference them from the AppXManifest. (The whitepaper also includes additional steps you can take if you want to localize the app's content as well).

Answer (score 0):

The desktop bridge app's display name have changed when you using `ms-resource:AppName` to localize strings in your app package manifest, you can see the change on the **Start Menu**.

Desktop bridge will package your desktop app to have UWP apps's experiences such as live tiles and notifications, but the UI in your packaged app will still depend on your desktop app. You said the desktop bridge apps "didn't work", it should be something like the Window's Title in WPF app. You can change it on your desktop app's code by using the API 
of your app's platform to get the OS's language and change the Window's title. The `ms-resource:AppName` in the converted app package manifest will affect the app's display name on the Start menu but will not change the app's window's title which is set on the destop app.